# woocommerce checkout error : You dont have permission to edit this post

Tags: wordpress, checkout, woocommerce

i have some trouble here with my woocommerce account,

the problem is when i try to checkout from my checkout form, i always get this error message

"you dont have permission to edit this post"

i'm newbie in wocommerce , and i was search it on google but not get any information there..

here's the screenshoot

[image]

anybody here can help me please...

thanks before

Answer (score 0):

the error displayed was ‘you do not have permission to edit the post’.

It turned out to be related to a plugin, the wp-easy seo one, when I deactivate that plugin, the orders can be placed.

Turn it off and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error if you are using some payment gateway like Instamojo (in my case) you can try with COD option enabled with COD You'll be able to checkout if you want's to just enable the prepaid orders disable COD and check with your payment gateway provider.

This works for me.